# Why is my watson translate service method not working?

Tags: java, ibm-watson

I did imports of classes I'm using but it gives this message error:

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
        The method translate(String, String, String) in the type     LanguageTranslation is not applicable for the arguments (String, Language, Language)
    at ibm.Cognitive.Translate(Cognitive.java:20)
    at Teste.Watson.main(Watson.java:16)
```

My class:

```
package ibm;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import Teste.Watson;

 import java.util.Map;

 public class Cognitive implements Serializable{

    static public String Translate(ArrayList lista){
        LanguageTranslation service = new LanguageTranslation();
        service.setUsernameAndPassword(lista.get(0).toString(), lista.get(1).toString());

        TranslationResult translationResult = service.translate(lista.get(2).toString(), Language.ENGLISH, Language.SPANISH).execute();

        return lista.get(0).toString();
     }  
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have not used the API for Watson. However, judging by the error you are getting, it appears the translate service wants `(string, string, string)` arguments.

Fixes I would try, if I were coding this:

1. Use `Language.ENGLISH.toString()` and `Language.SPANISH.toString()` as args.
2. Simply type `"ENGLISH"`, `"SPANISH"` as the args for language, thus sending string literals in to the function.

Comment: I understood that receives three strings but the problem is to run.
Gives error.

Comment: The code needs to put this line to run with this method.:
 TranslationResult translationResult = service.translate("hello","pt","it").execute();